# Inline help text for entries

Tags: control-panel, entry, field, admin, documentation

As a content strategist, I'm trying to take the memory and guesswork out of my client's experience while updating the site (check out this great article, "[Training the CMS](http://alistapart.com/article/training-the-cms)"). Field instructions are great for that. But I'm doing some things that aren't intuitive to the user on the back end, and I want to add instructions/explanation on the affected entry types.

I think this could be effective in various places:

1. Above the Title field
2. In an Instructions tab
3. Above or below the right sidebar

[image: outside course entry type]

**Is there a field type that would let me just include text with no user interaction? Or a way to add instructional text to the entry interface?** Bonus if I have the option to include images, links, and basic formatting too. I haven't explored plugins yet, because I'm still learning my way around Craft, but I'm open to using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it! The [Sprout Notes Field plugin](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/fields/docs/overview/notes-field) was what I needed. It allows HTML input with various formatting options.

[image: course page with help text]